# Changing order of attribute data in InfoWindow on click of multiple features

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-web-appbuilder, infowindow

I have an Esri Web AppBuiler 2.7 standalone web application where it is required that we are able to control the order of attribute data appearing in an InfoWindow on clicking multiple features.

For example, on click at a point on the map there might be several features overlapping each other. The Esri out of the box InfoWindow allows us to navigate through associated attribute data of each overlapping feature by click Next/Previous button on top right corner of the InfoWindow popup.

Is there any way to control the order in which the feature data appears? Please refer to attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of "SetFeatures" event of Map's InfoWindow to get the selected features before an InfoWindow is shown and rearrange them using feature's properties and general array functions.

```
map.infoWindow.on("SetFeatures",function(){
          var selectedFeatures = map.infoWindow.features;
        })
```